# nsubj for the first verb in a chain following dep → head path; DependencyMatcher in SpaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm working with DependencyMatcher from SpaCy. My goal is to find the subject that is in relation to a particular phrase.

For example, I want to find out who is "responsible" for a conversation. In the following sentences, I want to identify "Albert", and "nonnative".

> Albert is immersed in communication

> When a nonnative has better communication skills than you

But not "I" in the next sentence.

> I think Albert is immersed in communication

I came up with the following clarification, but I am not sure if it covers all instances. The pattern should search for **the nominal subject for the first verb in a chain following dep → head path.**

I started with this pattern, but it does not work correctly.

```
pattern = [    
    {
        "RIGHT_ID": "anchor_communicate",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"LEMMA": "communication"}
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "anchor_communicate",
        "REL_OP": "<<",
        "RIGHT_ID": "communication_verb",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"POS": "VERB"},
    },
    {
        "LEFT_ID": "communication_verb",
        "REL_OP": ">",
        "RIGHT_ID": "communicate_subject",
        "RIGHT_ATTRS": {"DEP": {"IN": ["nsubj", "nsubjpass"]}},
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have to use DependencyMatcher? I believe you could find the first verb by yielding `token.ancestors`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't necessary to use DepenencyMatcher, a possible solution could be:

```
text = "Albert is immersed in communication. When a nonnative has better communication skills than you. I think Albert is immersed in communication"
doc = nlp(text)
comm_token = [token for token in doc if token.lemma_ == "communication"]
for token in comm_token:
    for ancestor in token.ancestors:
        # find only the closest verb
        if ancestor.pos_ == "VERB":
            verb_token = ancestor
            subject = [tkn for tkn in verb_token.lefts if tkn.dep_ in ["nsubj", "nsubjpass"]][0]
            print(subject.text, verb_token.text, token.text)
            break
```

This outputs

```
Albert immersed communication
nonnative has communication
Albert immersed communication
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and wanted to post my code, but you were first:) Thank you!